# Nesting xibs inside UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have got a view that it is repeated in other views. So, to avoid repeat code and xibs I want to nested the child xib inside other xib (parent).

For that purpose, my parent xib has got a View that then I'm going to instantiate the child xib programatically.

I use this post http://www.secretlab.com.au/blog/2012/06/17/embedding-external-nibs-for-fun-and-profit to guide me.

But my problem is if I do that in UITableViewCells. I want reusable cells to be efficient. I have to instantiate the subview always. How I can avoid that?

My code:

```
 cellForRowAtIndexPath:

 DetailPostCell *cell = (DetailPostCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:REUSE_IDENTIFIER_DETAIL_POST_CELL];

   if (cell == nil) {

       UINib* customCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:REUSE_IDENTIFIER_DETAIL_POST_CELL bundle:nil];
       [tableView registerNib: customCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:REUSE_IDENTIFIER_DETAIL_POST_CELL ];

       cell = (DetailPostCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:REUSE_IDENTIFIER_DETAIL_POST_CELL];
   }

   /*Inflate subiview*/
   SubViewCell *subCell = [SubViewCell loadFromNib]; 
   [cell.view addSubview:subCell];


   [cell fillCellWithPost:post];

   return cell;



+ (SubViewCell *)loadFromNib { 
     UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:nil]; 
    NSArray* objects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil]; 

    return [objects objectAtIndex:0]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `DetailPostCell` class, this is where you should be adding the  `SubViewCell` view, not inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

This way you aren't adding the subview every time, irrespective of cell reuse.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Code to dequeue DetailPostCell

[cell updateSubviewPost:post];
}
```

updateSubviewPost will then use the reference to the subview added to populate as necessary.

Comment: But If I do that, then, when the cell is reuse the subview is empty. So, the first cells is well but the others cells are wrong

Comment: You can store a reference to the subview in the parent view and then populate it in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Can't you do the setup in `- prepareForReuse` in the subclass of the cell?

Comment: If I've misunderstood, please give more context and code.

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier does not reinstantiate the child nib that I load programatically, even if I do inside DetailPostCell . Or in which method of DetailPostCell (extends UITableViewCell) I have to add the subview? My scope is that when I use "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" the subview will be load too, but I try different cases and I can't. So I load in every call of "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and I think it's not efficient

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do. Inside DetailPostView, you can add the SubviewCell as subview - either in awakeFromNib or inside the init method for your UITableViewCell subclass. In here you can store reference to the subview and on each hit of cellForRowAtIndexPath you can update the cell and its subviews accordingly.